# In R how do I compute the estimated odds ratio of ratings for 2 different groups?

Tags: r

I have a table in R like this:

```
Institution  favorable  non_favorable   
Bank         70         150            
Credit Union 66          81
```

and I need to compute the estimated odds ratio of being rated as outstanding for credit unions compared to banks.

Do I use odds-ratio or is it a Fisher's exact test?

Comment: `fisher.test` should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You calculate the odds ratio as:

> odds of favorable in bank : p(favorable in bank) / p(non_favorable in
>   bank) odds of favorable in credit : p(favorable in credit union) /
>   p(non_favorable in credit union)
>
> odds ratio: odds of favorable in bank / odds of favorable in credit

So in your table:

```
x=structure(c(70, 66, 150, 81), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("Bank", "Credit_Union"), c("favorable", "non_favorable"
    )))
x
             favorable non_favorable
Bank                70           150
Credit_Union        66            81
```

The OR is (70/150)/(66/81), or if you use the table:

```
(x[1]/x[3])(x[2]/x[4])
0.5727273
```

As @Dave2e pointed out, you can use fisher.test on the 2x2. However note that the odds ratio estimate from fisher.test is a maximum likelihood estimate,

From the  vignette of fisher.test:

> estimate: an estimate of the odds ratio. Note that the conditional
>   Maximum Likelihood Estimate (MLE) rather than the unconditional MLE
>   (the sample odds ratio) is used. Only present in the 2 by 2 case.

And we can look at the results:

```
fisher.test(x)

Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  x
p-value = 0.01509
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.3637406 0.9027961
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
 0.5736073
```

So it is slightly different from the raw odds ratio I calculated above.